# What is type of app server play utilises?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

What type of server is play activator using ?

A play app can be deployed as a war using : `play war myapp -o myapp.war` and supports a wide range of servers described at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.2.1/deployment

The play server used from activator console, is this a variation of Tomcat or what type of server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play is it's own server. Underneath it's built on Netty for HTTP, but it doesn't use an app server.

Answer (score 0):

Play doesn't require an application server.  Typically Play is used standalone.

Also, your link is to an ancient version of the documentation.